# Move array of div images on click to a particular position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have array of images enclosed in a DIV

Code

```
<div id='brand'>
   <a href='#brand'><img src='brand.jpg' /> </a>
</div> 

<div id='fashion'>
   <a href='#fashion'><img src='fashion.jpg' /> </a>
</div> 

<div id='trend'>
   <a href='#trend'><img src='trend.jpg' /> </a>
</div> 

<div id='latest'>
   <a href='#latest'><img src='latest.jpg' /> </a>
</div>
```

**//Display will be like**

---

```
   BrandImage      FashionImage      trendImage     latestImage
```

---

If i click any one of the images

### I want the particular layout (Eg: trendImage clicked)

```
               BrandImage     FashionImage     latestImage



 trendImage      Text About Image Clicked
```

---

I am really starting with Jquery so i don't really have much of an idea about hove to animate the clicked image to the start position and display text based on that image and move the other image above.

--**Update**

I have Updated My code and Created as JSFIDDLE

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F3L78/1/)

Now i can get the div clicked to first but i need to animate it and move other dive above and display text based on clicked link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KjveG/

Comment: Thank You it put me on the right track, but it display text of all clicked div , not the text of the div clicked currently.

Comment: I've edited my fiddle. As far as I can tell, the simplest way to achieve what you are looking for is to have a second link that appears when the first is clicked, rather than actually moving the first link. It will appear the same to the viewer. Now when you click the second link, it makes the original reappear. http://jsfiddle.net/KjveG/3/

Comment: Its is working mostly , but how do clear the text display pane and only display the clicked div only .

Comment: @MichaelPeterson - In future, please don't put only jsfiddle's link in your answer but also put code here. As the answer will become invalid if jsfiddle.net is down.